# Dojox DataGrid : lose focus on a cell when validating?

Tags: datagrid, focus, blur, dojo

I have a popup with a DataGrid (with editable cells) and a validating button. If I set a value in a cell just before and don't leave it by selecting another cell, I don't get this value when validating. I know how to go through each cell of this grid and see if there is a focused one :

```
dojo.query("#myGrid .stdCell").forEach(function(node, idx){
    if(dojo.attr(node,'class').indexOf('dojoxGridCellFocus') > -1) {
        // But what to do here? 
    }
}
```

I think I have to blur this cell or focus another element of the popup but how can I do that? Or is there a simpler a function for this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working with a little workaround.

I added to my grid :

```
onBlur="onTableBlur"
```

And in my JS file :

```
var onTableBlur = function() {
    if (this.edit.isEditing()) {
        this.edit.apply(); 
    }
};
```